# Typo3 inlcudeJS only on specific pages

Tags: javascript, typescript, typo3, typoscript

i tried various options to include a javascript file within the setup.typoscript file only for specific pages, but couldn't get it running. The idea is, that i can include script files only to specific pages with a specific ID. For example i tried:

```
[page ["uid"] == 5]
    page.30.includeJSFooter = EXT:polyrama_museum/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Src/startpage.js
[END]
```

Where i want the "startpage.js" file only loading on the page with the "uid" 5 (which is the startpage in my case). Also i put the top command at the very bottom of the setup file outside the page object, but also within the page {} object, it's not running. Can anybody please help me? That would be great, as i searched now for a solution long time.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using? Is this JS file coming from an extension which is include on the page with the UID 5?

Comment: Another idea is to load the script in the controller. So you can put the plugin where you want and the script is loaded there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[page["uid"] == 5]
    page.includeJSFooter.polyrama_museum_startpage = EXT:polyrama_museum/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Src/startpage.js
[END]
```

`includeJSFooter` is a property of `PAGE` (which I assume `page` is an instance of) and it's an array. The `polyrama_museum_startpage` key is just descriptive, so if you want to use something else you can.

Also, I'm not sure if a space between `page` and `["uid"]` is allowed

Comment: aaah thanks man. Your answer helped a lot. I guess i just the snytax mistake that the includeJSFooter element was not a direkt child to page. Thans again. Great work.